# How to do hotfix for C++ based application

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, hotfix

We develop software based on Qt/C++ for internal use. The software is put in a server where few persons have the right to write. How can I do a hotfix in this case? For example, how can I replace a dynamic library (so or dll) of this software located in the server where the user does not have the right to change by a new lib with bug fixed located in the home directory of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply produce a new executable and new libs and if you have the rights to write on the folder, just replace those files.
Otherwise, ask to the owners of permissions to do it. It is a simple rights permission problem